# Custom scoring function for grid search classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, grid-search

I would like to perform a `GridSearchCV` for a `RandomForestClassifier` in scikit-learn, and I have a custom scoring function that I would like to use.

The scoring function will only work if probabilities are supplied (e.g.  `rfc.predict_proba(...)` must be called instead of `rfc.predict(...)`)

How can I instruct GridSearchCV to use `predict_proba()` instead of `predict()`?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

def my_custom_loss_func(ground_truth, predictions):
    # predictions must be probabilities - e.g. model.predict_proba()
    # example code here:
    diff = np.abs(ground_truth - predictions).max()
    return np.log(1 + diff)

param_grid = {'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100], 'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300]}
grid = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid=param_grid,
                    scoring=my_custom_loss_func)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object): The callable should have parameters (estimator, X, y)

Then you can use in your definition, `estimator.predict_proba(X)`

Alternatively, you can use [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) with `needs_proba=True`

A full code example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X, y = make_classification()
def my_custom_loss_func_est(estimator, X, y):
    # predictions must be probabilities - e.g. model.predict_proba()
    # example code here:
    diff = np.abs(y - estimator.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]).max()
    return -np.log(1 + diff)

def my_custom_loss_func(ground_truth, predictions):
    # predictions must be probabilities - e.g. model.predict_proba()
    # example code here:
    diff = np.abs(ground_truth - predictions[:, 1]).max()
    return np.log(1 + diff)

custom_scorer = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, 
                            greater_is_better=False,
                            needs_proba=True)
```

Use the scorer object:

```
param_grid = {'min_samples_leaf': [10, 50], 'n_estimators': [100, 200]}
grid = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid=param_grid,
                scoring=custom_scorer, return_train_score=True)
grid.fit(X, y)
pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)[['mean_test_score',
                                   'mean_train_score',
                                   'param_min_samples_leaf',
                                   'param_n_estimators']]

    mean_test_score mean_train_score    param_min_samples_leaf    param_n_estimators
0         -0.505201        -0.495011                        10                   100
1         -0.509190        -0.498283                        10                   200
2         -0.406279        -0.406292                        50                   100
3         -0.406826        -0.406862                        50                   200
```

Using the loss function directly is easy as well

```
grid = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid=param_grid,
                scoring=my_custom_loss_func_est,     return_train_score=True)
grid.fit(X, y)
pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)[['mean_test_score',
                                   'mean_train_score',
                                   'param_min_samples_leaf',
                                   'param_n_estimators']]

    mean_test_score mean_train_score    param_min_samples_leaf  param_n_estimators
0         -0.509098        -0.491462                        10                100
1         -0.497693        -0.490936                        10                200
2         -0.409025        -0.408957                        50                100
3         -0.409525        -0.409500                        50                200
```

Results differ due to different cv folds (I assume, but I am too lazy right now to set a seed and edit again (or is there a better way to paste code without the need of indenting everything manually?))

Comment: Using `sklearn==0.23.2`, when using the scorer object (`scoring=custom_scorer`), it gives this error `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed` and it points to this line `diff = np.abs(ground_truth - predictions[:, 1]).max()`. It seems to suggest that `predictions` is a 1D array, but it is being indexed like a 2D array. This is confusing because `.predict_proba()` should return a 2D array so indexing it using `[:, 1]` should be fine. Any clues about what could be causing this error?